# custom log using spark

Tags: log4j, apache-spark

I´m trying to configure a custom log using spark-submit, this my configure:

```
driver:
-DlogsPath=/var/opt/log\
-DlogsFile=spark-submit-driver.log\
-Dlog4j.configuration=jar:file:../bin/myapp.jar!/log4j.properties\

spark.driver.extraJavaOptions -> -DlogsPath=/var/opt/log -DlogsFile=spark-submit-driver.log -Dlog4j.configuration=jar:file:../bin/myapp.jar!/log4j.properties

executor:
-DlogsPath=/var/opt/log\
-DlogsFile=spark-submit-executor.log\
-Dlog4j.configuration=jar:file:../bin/myapp.jar!/log4j.properties\

spark.executor.extraJavaOptions -> -DlogsPath=/var/opt/log -DlogsFile=spark-submit-executor.log -Dlog4j.configuration=jar:file:../bin/myapp.jar!/log4j.properties
```

The spark-submit-drive.log is created and filled fine but spark-submit-executor.log is not crated

any idea?

Comment: Do you have the log4j configuration file replicated in all your slaves machines?

Comment: is this resolved ?

Answer (score 1):

Please try using log4j while running your job through spark submit.

Example:

```
spark-submit -- class com.something.Driver 
--master yarn \
--driver-memory 1g \
--executor-memory 1g \
--driver-java-options '-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/absolute path to   log4j property file/log4j.properties' \
--conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions '-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/absolute path to log4j property file/log4j.properties' \
jarfilename.jar
```

Note: You have to define both the properties with  driver-java-options and conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions, also you can use the default log4j.properties

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use

```
 --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/Users/feng/SparkLog4j/SparkLog4jTest/target/log4j2.properties"
```

or

--file

```
/Users/feng/SparkLog4j/SparkLog4jTest/target/log4j2.properties
```

The below submit it works for me.

```
bin/spark-submit --class com.viaplay.log4jtest.log4jtest --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/Users/feng/SparkLog4j/SparkLog4jTest/target/log4j2.properties"  --master local[*]  /Users/feng/SparkLog4j/SparkLog4jTest/target/SparkLog4jTest-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```